# Doesn't redshift allow us to alter a varchar field to date field?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Doesn't redshift allow us to alter a varchar field to a date field? I have multiple tables that need an existing varchar column to be converted to the date column.

```
Alter table <table_name> alter column <column_name> date;
```

This doesn't work.

Any leads on this?

Comment: are you sure that you don't have any data in this varchar-column or this data can be converted to date?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Alter table <table_name> alter column <column_name> TYPE date;` (with `TYPE`)?